# How to convert a date to julian date(not julian day number) in sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, julian-date

I am trying to convert a column having date in YYYY-MM-DD format to julian date in SQLite. The only solution I've found so far is julianday() which converts it to julian day number.

Tried julianday() function.

```
SELECT julianday(Column) from Table
```

Example: julianday(2019-06-24) converts to 1989.0

```
SELECT julianday(2019-06-24)
```

gives the result as `1989.0` which is julianday number whereas what I am expecting is julian date in 5 digit format i.e. `19175` `YYDDD`

Comment: In any case using `SELECT julianday(2019-06-24)` is wrong. It should be: `SELECT julianday('2019-06-24')` which returns: `2458658.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
SELECT strftime('%Y%j', '2019-06-24')
```

returns:

```
2019175
```

If you use [`substr()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) also:

```
SELECT substr(strftime('%Y%j', '2019-06-24'), 3)
```

or:

```
SELECT substr(strftime('%Y%j', '2019-06-24'), -5)
```

returns:

```
19175
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks buddy.